# Passing File Data using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with both file and text inputs. I want to pass file to a different php file and text data to a different file. I am having trouble passing file data to the other php file using jQuery and Ajax

Comment: Welcome to [so], please provide if possible a [mcve]. Also please let us know what you've tried so far and what the issues seem to be.

Comment: I think you find this please look https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the same using the following code. The code will post the uploaded file to the server using AJAX
HTML File

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<input id="default_file" type="file" name="music"/>


<script>
    $('#default_file').change(function(){    
//on change event  
alert("hi");
formdata = new FormData();
if($(this).prop('files').length > 0)
{
    file =$(this).prop('files')[0];
    formdata.append("music", file);
}
alert("hi2");

$.ajax({
url: "php_file_path.php",
type: "POST",
data: formdata,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function (result) {
     alert(result);
     // if all is well
     // play the audio file
}
   });
   });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

PHP File

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["music"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    $file = $_FILES["music"]["tmp_name"];
 echo $file;
    // now you have access to the file being uploaded
    //perform the upload operation.
    //move_uploaded_file( $file, "uploads/" . $file);
}
echo "ji";
?>
```